# max function within integrate.quadrature fails

Tags: python, scipy, integral

The following basic Python script fails:

```
from scipy import integrate
integrate.quadrature(lambda t: max(1,t), -2, 2)[0]
```

with the error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It looks to me that the `integrate.quadrature` command does not like the `max` function but I do not understand why.

Comment: Do you understand what max does?

Comment: @MadPhysicist well, it should take the max of 1 and t

Comment: Fair. But what is `t`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist The `t` considered in the quadrature procedure. If we simplify to some basic Riemann sum, we should have \int_{-2}^2 \max (1,t)dt \approx \sum_i max(1,t_i)\Delta t_i and the `max` function is well defined for every t_i. Since most quadrature schemes work in a similar fashion, I do not see where the problem is.

Comment: I hate to ruin @MadPhysicist punchline, but integrate.quadrature is not putting in a scalar value for t at multiple values to do this integration. It's attempting to vectorize the calculation by using a numpy array instead. You can reproduce this error by running `max(1, np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))`. You can fix this by using a vector-friendly version of your function `np.where(t > 1, t, 1)`.

Comment: @MichaelCao Thanks but what if the max involves complicated functions f1(t) and f2(t), ie max(f1(t),f2(t)) for which it is practically impossible to simplify the max by hand? Should I rely on a personal implementation of the quadrature procedure similar to the Riemann sum?

Comment: @pluton. `np.maximum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy` is not passing a scalar or 1-element array to your function, so it needs to be vectorized:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

integrate.quadrature(lambda t: np.maximum(1, t), -2, 2)[0]
```

You will get a warning like

```
AccuracyWarning: maxiter (50) exceeded. Latest difference = 6.366377e-04
```

However, the result will be close to the expected value of 4.5:

```
4.499480255789206
```

Here is a plot for reference:

```
t = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
plt.plot(t, np.maximum(1, t))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! I find it a bit strange that the accuracy cannot get higher... I have played with `tol` and `rtol` [1] without success. [1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html

Comment: @pluton You need to increase the number of evaluations: `maxiter=100` for example. Tolerance allows you to terminate before `maxiter` evaluations are reached. The warning is complaining that it takes too long, so making the tolerance looser might help, but probably won't.